# Is it possible to negotiate and respect the local culture and law

Tags: sharia, practical-islam

Is it possible for muslims to accept the local laws(and culture)when they are living in a foreign country ?

For example, France.
Is it possible for muslims to compromise not to pray in public or wear the head gear ?
Or is it something essentially non negotiable ?

What if the local legislative body decides to ban halal, and so on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Muslim in general is required to obey the law of the land he/she resides in and to follow all agreements they live under.

If the law conflicts with something that is obligatory in Islam, then it becomes incumbent upon them to move to a land where there is no such conflict. Allah says in the Qur'an:

> Is not the earth of Allah wide enough so that you could migrate? [Nisa':97](http://quran.com/4/97)

In democratic countries where the people get a say in deciding the laws, it becomes incumbent upon the Muslims to work within established channels to change those laws, because this is legal and permitted and encouraged. Doing so outside these means is expressly prohibited religiously.

When a religious action is not obligatory for a Muslim (e.g. praying in public) then there is no conflict. Women (and men) to cover their `awrah in public is obligatory; so is eating halal. Eating meat itself is not obligatory however, of course. Halal is a wider term than just for meat.

Comment: You're talking about refugees who seek shelter in none Muslim societies, they are forced to sign agreements. What about Muslim who is native to that land, but governed by none Muslim? They've not signed any agreements, are they then also required to follow the law of none Muslim?

Comment: When you are a citizen of a country, you are bound to its laws, even if you didn't explicitly sign anything. If one doesn't agree with those laws and doesn't want to abide by them, one is free to leave. This is the way of the modern nation-state and also of societies before, and also of Islamic lands of the classical period.

Comment: Immigration is just one out of many options, don't pretend leaving is the primary option available in this predicament.

Comment: On refugees, you are asking for help to the foreign government. Refugees are not forced to do anything. Refugees themselves ask help for a foreign government.

Answer (score 1):

If you compromise one part of yourself, then you'll find it easy to compromise the rest. It is better not to compromise.

The best solution to this current predicament is Muslim Zones. Muslim population of those nations should come to one area, buy all the property and rent out only to Muslim and those who are willing to live under Muslim regulations.

The above is the most efficient solution, another solution is Hijra/migration, which can be difficult because you're moving to unfamiliar territory, even if that territory is governed by Muslim.

Comment: Do you not realise renting out property only to muslims is a form of discrimination ? Also, what if the law prohibits wearing the head gear ? It will be prohibited any part of the country, no matter what the majority population is. I am not a christian but, for example, will any Islamic country allow Christians do this in their country ?

Comment: It is not discrimination at all, just as it is not discrimination to rent wealthy houses to wealthy people. It is up to the property owner to decide what condition must the tenants meet. I have seen advertising where the property owner refuses to accept certain nationalities as tenants etc.. This is not discrimination, this is preference based on belief, and everyone does business based on a set of belief that is not in favor of a segment of the society.

Comment: The poor simply cannot afford an expensive house. So you would accept it if you can't get a house because you are muslim ? Also, what about you statement that muslims can live in one area with muslim laws ? Enforcing muslim laws that go again the law of the government will be still illegal as long as you are in the foreign country.

Comment: If I can accept not getting a house simply because I'm poor, I can accept not getting a house simply because I'm Muslim. I didn't talk about enforcing Muslim law, rather making agreements with the tenants that Islamic Law and tradition will be respected as a tenancy condition. If the two parties agree to such conditions, it is not against the law.